# NetBeans ANT: <zip> is not including hidden files?

Tags: netbeans, ant, directory, zip, hidden

At the end of my Clean/Build, I wanted to always automatically copy the project folder into a zip for easy transfer. So I added this to my post build `<target>` in `build.xml`:

```
<zip zipfile="../project-xyz.zip" basedir=".." includes="project-xyz/**" excludes="*/dir/lib/**"/>
```

This works great on Windows, but on Linux, it removes any `.hidden` folders and all their children. I even tried

```
<zip zipfile="../project-xyz.zip" basedir=".." includes="project-xyz/**,project-xyz/.hidden/**" excludes="*/dir/lib/**"/>
```

and it still doesn't work.

What can I do to bring those files into the zip?

I am not opposed to detecting non-Windows environments and using `<exec>` on the `zip` command, though I am not sure how I would do that, and I am not sure I really want to, especially if there is a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what gets excluded by default from the zip by adding the following line in ant

```
<defaultexcludes echo="true"/>
```

And then use

```
<defaultexcludes add=.../>
```

and

```
<defaultexcludes remove=.../>
```

to customize what gets excluded by default.

Reference: [Ant docs for DefaultExcludes](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/defaultexcludes.html)

EDIT

You can also do

```
<zip defaultexcludes="no" .../>
```

Reference: [Ant docs for Zip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)

Comment: Note that this applies to all further ant task that use the default excludes, but since you are doing it at the end it should be fine.